# sending data from client to server for cookie store empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies

I have a server api code that sets the cookies,
defining the user data via req.body isn't setting the cookie with empty object.
But works fine when sending a predefined data in server code.

Server code:

```
router.get("/addCartToCookie", function(req, res){
  let options = {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15,
    httpOnly: true, 
    path: "/",
    sameSite: "strict",
  };

  let cartData = {
    name: req.body.name,
    slug: req.body.slug,
    productPictures: req.body.productPictures,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
  };

  // Set cookie
  res.cookie("cartName", cartData, options); // options is optional
  res.send("Cart Added to Cookie");
});
```

Client Code:

```
  const addToCartCookie = () => {
    console.log("Calling add to cart cookie");
    axios
      .get(
        "http://localhost:4001/api/addCartToCookie",
        {
          name: product.name,
          slug: product.slug,
          productPictures: product.productPictures[0].img,
          description: "sabdsjbfjsd",
          price: product.storePrice,
          quantity: itemCount,
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Try just setting it to an empty string when empty.

Comment: @firstlast How?

Comment: Something like `Object.values(cartData).length === 0 ? '': cartData;`

Comment: @firstlast still same

Comment: Could you just delete the cookie if empty?

Comment: Yes I could @firstlast

Comment: Yeah, seems like deleting the cookie and checking for it's existence probably seems like a better option.

Comment: adding delete if empty isnt setting the cookie at all

Comment: You only need to delete it if it already exist. If it doesn't exist, just don't set an empty cookie.

Comment: @firstlast Im confused

Comment: Seems straight-forward. Maybe someone else can help you.